# Centered, equal width, columned items using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a column of 4 items. All the items have different widths due to different content. Using flexbox, Does anyone know how I can make all the items the same width as the largest item while keeping them all centered please?

Here's what I have at the moment.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item 1</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
   </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item 2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item 3</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
    </ul>
   </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item 4</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change display flex to `inline-flex` and remove the `align-items: center` and set `text-align: center` on the `body`

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: left;
}

.item {
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item 1</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
   </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item 2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item 3</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
    </ul>
   </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item 4</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the container `inline-flex` and put text-align center on the parent

```css
body {
  /*or parent container*/
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item 1</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item 2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item 3</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item 4</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create one more `flex-container` inside `container` div and remove `align-items: center` from that element so that flex items inside will `stretch`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

 .inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Item 1</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h3>Item 2</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h3>Item 3</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h3>Item 4</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code in your css:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```